# xCode SQLite Swift4 DB Error: 1 "no such table: medicamentos2"

Tags: ios, sqlite

I am trying to read a SQLite database of preloaded data, in swift xcode 9, but apparently it opens the database but, it does not find the table, it gives me the following message:
DB Error: 1 "no such table: medicamentos2"
I have the following code to copy it.

```
func getPath(_ fileName: String) -> String {

     let bundlePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Data", ofType: ".db")
     let destPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
     let fileManager = FileManager.default
     let fullDestPath = URL(fileURLWithPath: destPath).appendingPathComponent("Data.db")
     if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: fullDestPath.path){
        print("Database file is exist")
        print(fileManager.fileExists(atPath: bundlePath!))
     }else{
        do{
            try fileManager.copyItem(atPath: bundlePath!, toPath: fullDestPath.path)
        }catch{
            print("\n",error)
        }
     }

    print(fullDestPath.path)
    return fullDestPath.path
}
```

I do not know where I'm failing.
Thank you

Comment: Did u resolved the issue ? @Felix Alvarez